# windows and debian dual boot on lenovo 310: windows failed to boot

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot

I have a new laptop (Lenovo 310 ideapad without the NOVO button) shipped with windows 10. Using windows disk manager, I created 200GB partition for my debian linux because I want to have dual OS in my laptop.

I have debian installer in my usb drive so all i have to do is to change the boot order on BIOS. Some tutorial says that I have to push the NOVO button on my laptop in order to go to BIOS screen. As i said, my laptop doesn't have that button. I managed to open BIOS screen from windows login page by holding shift key and clicking the restart button in the right bottom corner of the screen, I changed the UEFI settings to support legacy system. I have to note this because it might be related to the problem I will describe later.

I run the debian installer. I set the 200GB unallocated partition to ext4 and split it a little bit for the swap space. After the installation, I restarted my laptop and the GRUB page showed up along with options to boot both from linux or windows. Unfortunately, windows failed to boot. It says "The boot configuration data for your PC is missing or contain errors" and to fix this I have to insert my installation disk. I don't have installation disk. The laptop is shipped as it is. I downloaded win 10 iso from microsoft website and made bootable usb drive using my old laptop (debian jessie). However, the usb drive failed to boot.

My questions:

1. What did I do wrong during the process of debian installation that affected the windows MBR?
2. What causing my windows 10 bootable usb drive failed to boot?
3. Additional question for Lenovo 310 ideapad users: what is the simplest way to open BIOS screen without NOVO button?

Answer (score 1):

@under5hell I changed the UEFI settings to support legacy system.

Your OS's are installed in 2 different mode. windows 10 Uefi/Efi and Debian in legacy mode. Install Debian in Efi mode. should be helpfull, I hope https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI#Booting_a_UEFI_machine_normally

Edit: the changes in Uefi, you have to turn back.

Answer (score -1):

The NOVO button is a little hole bside the headphone input. It is between headphone input and memory card input. Use a clip to push it.

Comment: "I have a new laptop (Lenovo 310 ideapad *without* the NOVO button"

Comment: There is NOVO button in ideapad310 @under5shell but without it u can boot into BIOS setup using Fn+F2